# What is the overhead of this operation to modify by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, containers, overhead

Let's say there is a large vector called `second`, and now I want my own vector `first` to point to the large vector. I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> second (100000,100);
void modify(std::vector<int>& i) {
  i = second;
}
int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> first(1, 1); 
  modify(first);    
  return 0;
}
```

Is it true that there is an overhead for `modify` function? Will the content of `second` to be cloned into a new array and then passed into `first`, or is it just passed by reference with negligible overhead?

Comment: There are no references here, only pointers.  But more importantly, your `modify` function doesn't actually do anything useful.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth sorry, I corrected my snippet just now

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux sorry, I corrected my snippet just now

Comment: You may want to do some research on the concept of move semantics. It allows you to transfer the value of an object to another compatible object (usually of the same type) with low constant complexity.

Comment: There's probably no "overhead" from doing this via a reference, at least not in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will *copy* the *entire vector*, and the complexity is linear in size of `second`, as stated in the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/).

What you did avoid by passing a reference as the function parameter is copying `first` into the parameter `i`. In other words, if your function was this (passing the vector by value-which would change the semantic of the function):

```
// more expensive!
void modify(std::vector<int> i) {
  i = second;
}
```

then you would pay the cost of copying `first` to `i`, plus the cost of copying `second` to `i`. Of course in your code, this would make no difference, since `i` is tiny, but in general it's a good practice to pass large objects by reference, in order to avoid unnecessary copies.

---

Tip: Study move semantics.

Comment: Thinking that might actually be a lot cheaper. Since nothing useful happens, the compiler may be able to optimize the call out.

Comment: Yeah if the optimization flags are enabled!

Comment: Accepting vector by value would change the semantic of the function.

Comment: Indeed @SergeyA, updated, thank you! However I though OP was confused and tried to clear that out.